# Python: Best way to store model values of a grid search

Tags: python, numpy, save

I'm doing a grid search for a fit of models to data. I want to be able to flexibly plot the model values (which are computed within my script) *after* the computation, in a separate script.

As such, I would like to store all the modelvalues at each grid point (identified by parameters a,b,c...), let's say a vector of length *m*, in such a way that it is (1) memory inexpensive and (2) I can read it in in such a way that I can easily access the model with parameters (a',b',c',...) and its chi-squared value (which I computed).

What is the best way to go about doing this in Python? I've been looking into using `numpy`'s [save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) or [savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) but I'm unsure how to do this / use these functions in a clean way.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how many values you have, and exactly what you mean by memory inexpensive. Personally though it sounds like a pandas data frame might be a good solution.